# Remove Ti.API.info() when building for stores?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

When I'm packaging an app for the App Store/Play Store, should I remove any calls to Ti.API.info() or will they be ignored or not even compiled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are still here, good man Fokke created a nice module, [ti-stealth](http://www.tidev.io/2014/04/17/remove-log-calls-from-production-code/) that does this work for you.

Comment: Thank you for the info, prompted me to come up with a quick and dirty solution, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution to not log messages in production:

Wrap Ti.API.log in a function in alloy.js:

```
function log (msg) {
    if (Alloy.CFG.debugging) {
        Ti.API.log('>>> ' + msg);
    }
}

log("My logged message");
```

Include `debugging` key in config.son:

```
{
    "global": {},
    "env:development": {
         "debugging":true
    },
    "env:test": {
         "debugging":true
    }, 
    "env:production": {
         "debugging":false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty but works : 
In alloy.js

```
function consLog(e)
{
    if (!ENV_PRODUCTION)
      console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

And use it :

```
consLog("Hello World");
```

Comment: This is not quick and dirty. More information can be found here : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Controllers-section-34636384_AlloyControllers-ConditionalCode